# Why does swagger-maven-plugin generate incorrect test addresses in swagger-ui?

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-ui

I am having problems using the `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-maven-plugin:2.2.7` to build the Swagger interface. This one is well generated and shows perfectly the methods of my REST API. However, the paths generated for the test function "TRY IT OUT" are incorrects.

For example, I have a method version of the UtilsRest service that is exposed on `http://localhost:8080/UtilsRest/api/version`.

[image: swagger-api-interface]

My method runs perfectly at that address through a browser. But the "TRY IT OUT" function points to http://localhost:8080/version and, not surprisingly, the call fails

[image]

Here is some code to contextualize my request. I deliberately chose the most basic method so that logic problems would not interfere.

- the dependency import in pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

- the plugin configuration in pom.xml

```
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-maven-plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputFileName>${project.name}</outputFileName>
          <outputPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WebContent</outputPath>
          <outputFormat>JSON</outputFormat>
          <resourcePackages>          
            <package>com.societe.unite.services</package>
          </resourcePackages>
          <prettyPrint>TRUE</prettyPrint>
          <sortOutput>TRUE</sortOutput>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>resolve</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

- content of the web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
         version="4.0">
  <display-name>UtilsRest</display-name>
  <default-context-path>UtilsRest</default-context-path>

  <servlet>
    <display-name>Rest Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.societe.unite</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
</web-app>
```

- content of the UtilsRest class

```
package com.societe.unite.services;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Contact;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.License;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;

@OpenAPIDefinition
(
    info = @Info
    (
        title = "UtilsRest",
        version = "1.0.0",
        description = "API du projet UtilsRest",
        license = @License
        (
            name = "Creative Commons CC BY",
            url = "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/deed.fr"
        ),
        contact = @Contact
        (
            email = "thierry.heirman@societe.com",
            name = "Thierry Heirman"
        )
    )
)


@Tag(name = "Utils")
@Path("")
public class Utils implements IUtils
{
    @GET 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("version")
    public String getVersion()
    {
        return "1.0";
    }
}
```

*(I warned you that I chose the most basic example :D )*

Please help me to find out why my paths are generated incorrectly.

Thank you, have a nice day

Thierry